# Use ssl certificate in SOAP client

Tags: java, ssl, soap, pfx

I am creating a SOAP client to communicate with a webservice. 
I have a .pfx certificate in order to communicate with the webservice but I'm not sure how to use it.

If I understand correctly, I need to load the certificate into the jvm. This is what I have right now:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path/to/cert.pfx");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "qwerty123");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");

OrderResponseType response = locator.getRpServiceSoapPort().authenticate(authRequest);
```

However, running this code gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.bankid.RpService.v4_0_0.RpServiceSoapBindingStub.authenticate(RpServiceSoapBindingStub.java:342)
    at TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:23)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 28 more

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:DESKTOP-NT7GUOA

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.bankid.RpService.v4_0_0.RpServiceSoapBindingStub.authenticate(RpServiceSoapBindingStub.java:342)
    at TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:23)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 28 more
```

I have been searching the web for hours but I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The client needs a Truststore to accept the server's certificate, not a keyStore. As explained in the [Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization). The properties to set are :

- javax.net.ssl.trustStore
- javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
- javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType (not mandatory)

Comment: I set the properties as you told me to, but I still get the same errors.

Comment: add this JVM property then we know what keystores you are really using : -Djavax.net.debug=all

Comment: this error mesasges, are they coming from the client or the server ?

Comment: They are from the client. I do not have access to the server.

Comment: if you use the properties I said, and if the truststore contains the server's certificate, it is supposed to work. As we have doubts on both the truststore you are loading, and the certificates it contains, you need to add the JVM property to see what's really happening.

Comment: is the value really "<Subject>" instead of the FQDN you are requesting ?

Comment: No. I did not want to provide too much information. It looks correct to me however.

Comment: This Exception means that you're not trusting the certificate sent by the server. You believe you are, but you're not. Export the server's certificate with a browser and check its serial number with the one in your debug output. If they are the same, it's a Java bug. Check that you didn't change your hosts file to request another server than the one you want to request. Check nslookup solving too.

Comment: The certificate seems to be expired. Could that be the problem?

Comment: You would raise a CertificateExpired and not a Validation exception. When it is trusted, it is trusted, whatever expiry dates are. Please check both serials.

Comment: Well, I can't export the certificate since it's expired on the server.

Comment: If you have openssl, openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:{PORT} -showcerts

Comment: The serial numbers do not match.

Comment: I suppose you know what to do now.

Comment: I guess I'll contact the web services owner. Thank you for your help!